# Unexpected token, expected "," when trying to generate dynamic components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I try to generate only a specific component based on a criteria in react, i get unexpected token error. I'm using an arrow function inside a map function to check if any of the elements satisfy the criteria (the element should be 1 to be shown).

I have tried putting the `<{section} />` and `null` into parentheses but i don't think that's the problem. Here is my code:

```
import One from './components/One';
import Two from './components/Two';
import Three from './components/Three';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      section_to_show: {
        'One': 1,
        'Two': 0,
        'Three': 0,
      },
    };
  }
  render() {
    ...
    const section_renders = Object.keys(this.state.section_to_show).map(
      section => (
        this.state.section_to_show[section] ? <{section} /> : null
      )
    );
    return (
        ...
        {section_renders}
        ...
    );
   }
};
```

What am i doing wrong? I just can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: please put your code in codepen or codesandbox for people to help

Comment: I dont think you can interpolate a component name like `<{component_name} />`, you should use if-else/switch, to render conditionally.

Comment: **section => ()** should have curly braces, not parentheses. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @muka.gergely No, parentheses are used to return an object, either the component if state implies it or null for all the other components.

Comment: where are the components, `one two, three`?

Comment: @DamianGreen They are imported in the form of `import One from './components/One';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you want  to do:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

const One = () => <div>1</div>;
const Two = () => <div>2</div>;
const Three = () => <div>3</div>;

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    section_to_show: {
      One: <One />,
      Two: <Two />,
      Three: <Three />
    }
  };
  render() {
    const section_renders = ["One", "Two", "Three"].map(section =>
      this.state.section_to_show[section]
        ? this.state.section_to_show[section]
        : null
    );
    return <div>{section_renders}</div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Your code: `<{section} />` is invalid because you are trying to insert content within a fragment instead of wrapping a fragment tag around it `<>{content} </>`

Example codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-component-7mvbk

Comment: I'm trying to display components based on the value of section_to_show object. There are other components named 'one', 'two' and 'three' which i would like to display conditionally.

Comment: what does the value of `this.state.section_to_show` look like?

Comment: The `section_to_show` is for determining what component to show, I added another object similar to yours (i.e. `'One': One,`) But it results in showing nothing whatsoever: `this.state.section_to_show[section] ? <>{this.state.sections[section]} </> : null`

Comment: Thank you so much, Your latest edit fixed my problem :) I didn't add the < /> around the reference to components.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, i see what you are trying to achieve, 
First of all map returns an array and component name start from a capital letter that's how jsx distinguish between html elements and react Components 
so heres the solution

```
const section_renders = ['One', 'Two'].map(
  section => {
     return (
      this.state.section_to_show[section] ? this.state.section_to_show[section] : null 
      )
  }
);
return (

    <div>{section_renders.map(section => {
      if(section) {
        const Comp = section;
        return <Comp />
      } else {
        return null
      }
    })}</div>

);
```

and your state object should look like this

```
state = {
section_to_show: {
  One,
}
}
```

If you are still having some problem i have created a [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-snowflake-x6x6f) for you convenience

one other thing if your array have small letters like you have ['one'] you can easily map it to an object but i hope that's not too difficult

Hope it helps